# What are the alternatives to prelude's iterate if the "output" values are not the same as those being iterated on?

Tags: haskell

I have come across a pattern where, I start with a seed value `x` and at each step generate a new seed value and a value to be output. My desired final result is a list of the output values. This can be represented by the following function:

```
my_iter :: (a -> (a, b)) -> a -> [b]
my_iter f x = y : my_iter f x'
   where (x',y) = f x
```

And a contrived example of using this would be generating the Fibonacci numbers:

```
fibs:: [Integer]
fibs = my_iter (\(a,b) -> let c = a+b in ((b, c), c)) (0,1)
-- [1, 2, 3, 5, 8...
```

**My problem is that I have this feeling that there is very likely a more idiomatic way to do this kind of stuff. What are the idiomatic alternatives to my function?**

The only ones I can think of right now involve `iterate` from the Prelude, but they have some shortcomings.

One way is to iterate first and map after

```
my_iter f x = map f2 $ iterate f1 x
    where f1 = fst . f
          f2 = snd . f
```

However, this can look ugly if there is no natural way to split f into the separate f1 and f2 functions. (In the contrived Fibonacci case this is easy to do, but there are some situations where the generated value is not an "independent" function of the seed so its not so simple to split things)

The other way is to tuple the "output" values together with the seeds, and use a separate step to separate them (kind of like the "Schwartzian transform" for sorting things):

```
my_iter f x = map snd . tail $ iterate (f.fst) (x, undefined)
```

But this seems wierd, since we have to remember to ignore the generated values in order to get to the seed (the (f.fst) bit) and add we need an "undefined" value for the first, dummy generated value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already noted, the function you want is [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aunfoldr). As the name suggests, it's the opposite of `foldr`, but it might be instructive to see exactly why that's true. Here's the type of `foldr`:

```
(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

The first two arguments are ways of obtaining something of type `b`, and correspond to the two data constructors for lists:

```
[]  :: [a]
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

...where each occurrence of `[a]` is replaced by `b`. Noting that the `[]` case produces a `b` with no input, we can consolidate the two as a function taking `Maybe (a, b)` as input.

```
(Maybe (a, b) -> b) -> ([a] -> b)
```

The extra parentheses show that this is essentially a function that turns one kind of transformation into another.

Now, simply reverse the direction of both transformations:

```
(b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> (b -> [a])
```

The result is exactly the type of `unfoldr`.

The underlying idea this demonstrates can be applied similarly to other recursive data types, as well.

Comment: An interesting aspect of this is that the `Maybe (a, b)` part comes from `Maybe (a, _)` being the underlying functor of `[a]`, if you treat it as a (greatest, for unfolds) fixed point. The version that @missingno asked for is simply `unfoldr` for `Stream a`, whose underlying functor is `(a, _)`. The additional `Nothing` in the Prelude `unfoldr` just covers the case where you want to stop generating your list, but that will never happen here.

Comment: @copumpkin: That `[a]` is often used for all three of known-finite, known-infinite, and potentially-infinite lists is one of my persistent pet peeves. >:[

Answer (score 6):

The standard function you're looking for is called [unfoldr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr).

Answer (score 5):

[Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a very useful tool in this case, since it doesn't only support searching functions by name, but also by type.

In your case, you came up with the desired type [`(a -> (a, b)) -> a -> [b]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+%28a%2C+b%29%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+[b]). Entering it yields no results - hmm.

Well, maybe there's a standard function with a slightly different syntax. For example, the standard function might have its arguments flipped; let's look for something with [`(a -> (a, b))`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+%28a%2C+b%29%29) in its type signature somewhere. This time we're lucky as there are plenty of results, but all of them are in exotic packages and none of them seems very helpful.

Maybe the second part of your function is a better match, you want to generate a list out of some initial element after all - so type in [`a -> [b]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+[b]) and hit search. First result: [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) - bingo!

Comment: Hahaha, I originally tried the first search but gave up after that. As someone that is always telling people to use Hoogle, Ill have to take this a a lesson learned :)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is `iterateM` in `State` monad:

```
iterateM :: Monad m => m a -> m [a]
iterateM = sequence . repeat
```

It is not in standard library but it's easy to build.

So your `my_iter` is

```
evalState . sequence . repeat :: State s a -> s -> [a]
```

Comment: Or just use [the `monad-loops` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.3.3.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html) and get more variations on the idea than you ever knew you wanted. :]

Comment: monad-loops seem to be just a random collection of all possible loops. It's good but I'd prefer a small set of well-thought combinators. It's a pity that there's no something like `iterateUntil` in the standard library.